# Sharing memory mappings under Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-mapping, execve

### Motivation

I'd like to write a pair of programs where one program reads data and transfers it into an internal format and the other program transfers the internal format into something else. As an excercise, I want to code the interaction between these programs without the use of pipes. I rather like to use signals and shared memory.

### What I want

I have programs A and B where A calls B. How can I

1. Create a memory block from program A
2. Call program B from program A, giving it the information about where to find the memory block
3. Use the memory block from both programs.

More specific, A decodes a custom video format and places a single uncompressed frame into a shared buffer. B reads from the buffer and encodes it into an output strean. The decoder decodes up to 100 frames per second which is about 500 MiB/s memory traffic. Pipes turned out to be slow since the data has to be copyied much too often and the buffers aren't exactly big.

### What I think might work

My idea is to use `mmap(NULL,len,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0)` to create a section of shared memory. The problem  is, that the manpage of `execve(2)` states:

> Memory mappings are not preserved (mmap(2)).

So, how can I share that memory with the other program? Is it a better idea to put both functionality into one program and use `fork` instead?

Comment: You should go ahead with this as a learning exercise, but please be aware that making things work with shared state, in particular shared memory, is too difficult and should be avoided even at large costs. Chances are that the memory sharing will be more expensive anyway. As a friendly warning :)

Comment: @Magnus And how do you think should it be done? The shared state are two buffers for uncompressed pixel data. One process decodes images, the other encodes. Using a pipe proved to completely kill parallelity since a buffer of 512 bytes is just too small.

Comment: This is fine as an exercise, but shared memory is usually a very bad idea.  You might look at higher-level IPC like sockets or named pipes or zero-MQ.

Comment: It's not crazy for huge data. For example, SkypeKit uses shared memory for video transport since it affords high throughput without the overhead of other IPC mechanisms.

Comment: @nneonneo I added a paragraph on the size of the data.

Comment: @Magnus I added a paragraph on the size of the data

Comment: Actually, Python makes use of shared memory pretty much a no-brainer.  See the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Actually, pipes on Linux have a 64k buffer, 512 bytes is the POSIX minimum guaranteed atomic write size (which may be less than the pipe capacity, e.g: 64k are typically 16 pages, probably Linux doesn't guarantee atomicity for writes spanning multiple pages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*nix systems have several APIs for shared memory:

- BSD: use `mmap()`. To share memory between unrelated processes, you associate it to a file. You can also share memory between related processes using `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `fork()`ing (but make sure to use -1 as `fd` for portability).
- System V: (some people *really* dislike this one) use `shmget()` to create/get a reference to a shared memory area, attach to it via `shmat()`, detach via `shmdt()`, mark for deletion with `shmctl()`. You identify shared memory areas by a key, which should be unique.
- POSIX: use `shm_open()` then `mmap()` from the returned file descriptor.

Comment: File-backed `mmap()` for shared memory is not just for BSDs, it is POSIX too. Using a `MAP_SHARED` mapping, the shared object is in RAM, with pages only flushed to disk if `msync()` is called, or if there is a lot of memory pressure and the mapping has pages not accessed recently. Personally, I find `mmap(..,MAP_SHARED,..)` on a file the best option, especially with large amounts of data.